# Find a basis for $ImT$ and represent the image.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ be a basis of $(Z_7)^3$.
$$
B = (u_1,u_2,u_3)
$$

$$
u_1 = (1,2,3), u_2 = (1,6,0), u_3 = (1,1,1) 
$$

Let $T$ be a linear transformation satisfies:

$$
T:(Z_7)^3 \to (Z_7)^3
$$

$$
T(u_1) = (1,6,0), T(u_2) = (5,2,0), T(u_3) = (3,1,2)
$$

Find $\tag{a}[T]_b$

Bases for: 
$\tag{b} ImT, kerT$
Is $\tag{c}\exists a, (a,-1,a) \in ImT$

*My questions starts at b and c

---

$(a)$:  Using $B$ as a basis we want to represent $T(u)$ as a linear combination of the elements of the basis $B$, namely, building $[T]_B$.

$$
T(u_1) = (1,6,0) = 0u_1+1u_2+0u_3
$$
$$
T(u_2) = (5,2,0) = 0u_1+5u_2+0u_3 
$$
$$
T(u_3) = (3,1,2) = 0u_1+1u_2+2u_3
$$

Therefore, the representing matrix $[T]_B$ is: 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0 \\ 1&5&1 \\ 0&0&2\end{bmatrix}
$$

$(b)$
A basis for $ImT$ will be the independent columns, because the columns space spans $ImT$.
We can see that there are 2 independent columns, therefore a basis for $ImT$ will be: 
$$
b_1 = (0,1,0)^T, b_2 = (0,1,2)^T
$$

$$
B_{ImT} = \begin{bmatrix}0&0 \\ 1&1 \\ 0&2\end{bmatrix}
$$

To find a basis for the $kerT$, we will solve the system $[T]_Bx = 0$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0 \\ 1&5&1 \\ 0&0&2\end{bmatrix}x = 0
$$

$$
x_3 = 0, x_2 = t, x_1 = -5t
$$
General solution: 
$$
t(0,1,-5)
$$

We got a general solution that is build from 1 vector. therefore, $dim(kerT) = 1$, and its good, satisfing: 
$$dim(kerT) + dim(ImT) = n \Rightarrow 1 + 2 = 3$$

Therefore, a basis for the $kerT$ could be the vector: 
$$B_{kerT} = (0,1,-5)$$

(c) We can build the tranformation rule:

$$
G \in D(T), a_i \in Z_7
$$
$$
G = a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 + a_3u_3
$$
$$
T(G) = a_1T(u_1) + a_2T(u_2) + a_3T(u_3)
$$

$$
T(G) = (a_1+5a_2+3a_3,6a_1+2a_2+a_3,2a_3)
$$

### *Question:

By looking at the basis i built for $ImT$ it seems that the first element is always 0.

In contrast, by looking at $T(G)$ i have just build, it seems that the first element in the image, not always zero.

but $T(G)$ and $B_{ImT}$ both represent the same thing - $ImT$, no?

So how it look like they dont represent the same thing?

Where is my misunderstanding?

### *Edit:

That is what i did from what was explained to me. (and from what i understood)

we can calculate the general formula for $[y]_B$ using the basis for the $ImT$ we get:

$$
a_i \in Z_7, b_i \in [B_{ImT}], [y]_B = a_1b_1 + a_2b_2
$$

So we get the coordinate vector for y in B basis: 
$$
[y]_B = (0,a_1+a_2,2a_2)
$$

Now, we can get to represent $y$ in $B$ basis using the standard basis by multiplying the $[y]_B$ by $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$:

$$
y = [y]_B(u_1,u_2,u_3)^T =0u_1+(a_1+a_2)u_2 +2a_2u_3 \in ImT
$$

Therefore:

$$
y = (a_1+a_2+2a_3,6a_1+6a_2+2a_3,2a_3)
$$

Now, the question asks if $\exists a \in R \Rightarrow (a,-1,a) \in ImT$

So we check:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&2&|a \\ 6&6&2&|-1 \\ 0&0&2&|a\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{RREF} 
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&2&|a \\ 0&0&0&|-1+6a \\ 0&0&2&|a\end{bmatrix}
$$

Therefore, for $a = 6 \Rightarrow (a,-1,a) \in ImT$, otherewise, there is no solution for the system.

Comment: Too long a question. Unlikely that many people will read all that. Also, what does $\;T(3,1,2)\;$ mean in the 5th line?

Comment: I will ask a shorter question and delete this one

Comment: I disagree: the "question" part is distinctly outlined, I think it's fine

Comment: Note:
$$
B = \pmatrix{1&1&1\\2&6&1\\3&0&1}, \qquad B^{-1} = \pmatrix{2&2&3\\5&4&5\\1&1&6}
$$

Comment: I dont understand what and why you put the vectors u1,u2,u3 as columns and what did it give you nor why did you calculate (especially since it seems hard to calculate) the inverse matrix...

Comment: The $u_i$ are columns because I’m building a change of basis matrix. I’ve calculated these in case you want to use the formulas discussed in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to understand what the matrix $[T]_B$ does: it takes the coordinate vector of $x$ relative to $B$ (i.e. $[x]_B$) and yields the coordinate vector of $T(x)$ relative to $B$ (i.e. $[T(x)]_B$).  In short, we have
$$
[T(x)]_B = [T]_B [x]_B.
$$
You have correctly deduced that the vectors $b_1 = (0,1,0)$ and $b_2 = (0,1,2)$ form a basis for the column-space of $[T]_B$.  Correspondingly, every vector $y$ in the image of $T$ has a coordinate vector of the form 
$$
[y]_B = a_1 b_1 + a_2b_2 = (0,a_1 + a_2, 2a_2)
$$
for some $a_1,a_2 \in \Bbb Z_7$.  So, the coordinate vector of $y$ always has a zero in the first entry.

The corresponding vector $y \in \Bbb Z_7$ has the form
$$
y = 0 \cdot u_1 + (a_1 + a_2)u_2 + (2a_2) u_3.
$$
This vector does not necessarily have a $0$ in its first coordinate.  The vector $T(G)$ corresponds to some vector $y \in \operatorname{Im}(T)$ rather than to its coordinate vector $[y]_B$.

Comment: helpful, thank you. Something is weird, so take a $y = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$ in the standard basis, to change it to $[y]_B$ i use the $[B_{ImT}]$ like this: $[y]_B = [B_{ImT}]y $ and then i can conclude: $[T(x)]_B = [T]_B[y]_B =  [T]_B[B_{ImT}]y $ ?

And if i want to get the $T(G)$ i found, i do $[T]_B[y]_B(u_1,u_2,u_3)^T$ and i will get $T(G)$? thats the way?

Comment: Not good, i need to rethink, im doing alot of mistakes with this, very confusing

Comment: Maybe this will help: if $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is a coordinate-vector of $x$ relative to $B$, then the corresponding coordinates in the standard basis are 
$$
x = a_1 u_1 + a_2 u_2 + a_3 u_3 = \pmatrix{u_1 & u_2 & u_3} \pmatrix{a_1\\a_2\\a_3} = B\,[x]_B
$$

Comment: Im just having hard time understanding where is the standard connection $T(v) = Av$?

What is the representing matrix $A$ here?

Comment: $A$ here would be the matrix of $T$ relative to the standard basis.  The first column of $A$ would be $T(e_1)$, the second would be $T(e_2)$, and the third would be $T(e_3)$ where $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are the standard basis vectors (for instance, $e_2 = (0,1,0)$)

Comment: If you wanted to calculate $A$ using your matrix, we could note the following: $A$ is a matrix for which $Ax = T(x)$, and the relationship between $x$ and $[x]_B$ is $x = B[x]_B$, or equivalently $[x]_B = B^{-1}x$.  So, we have
$$
T(x) = B[T(x)]_B = B [T]_B [x]_B = B [T]_B B^{-1}x.
$$
That is, $T(x) = (B [T]_B B^{-1})x$ (for all $x \in \Bbb Z_7^3$.  So, $A = B[T]_B B^{-1}$.

Comment: For a more direct approach: we could solve the system $x_1 u_1 + x_2 u_2 + x_3 u_3 = e_1$ to find $x_1 = 2, x_2 = 5, x_3 = 1$ so that the first column of $A$ is
$$
T(e_1) = T(2u_1 + 5u_2 + 1u_3) = 2T(u_1) + 5T(u_2) + T(u_3)
$$

Comment: I too started looking for the change basis matrix. 

But why did you look just at the first column?

Comment: I just explained how to find the first column as an example; we could find every column of $A$ in the same way.

Comment: I don’t understand what you were trying to do with the matrix $B_{Im \ T}$ earlier

Comment: Im confused, i edited the end of the post - thats how i continued, is it the correct way?

Comment: We’ve been doing things differently because my vectors are column-vectors and yours are row-vectors

Comment: That being said your work is mostly correct. The conclusion you should have reached is that the vector will be in the column space iff $a=6$.

Comment: And i thought that just in a=6 i get no result because, while you say that the result wll be when a=6, why? if a = 6, there is no solutions to the matrix

Comment: When $a=6$ there are solutions because the middle equation is just $0=0$. For other values the middle equation is false, so there are no solutions to the system of equations.

Comment: Oh, oops, yea, thank you. My mistake. when $a \neq 6$, then there is no solution, sorry.